# Finite Difference Method for Solving ODEs Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, numerical-methods, ode, scientific-computing

I'm trying to devise an algorithm for the finite difference method, but I'm a bit confused. The ODE in question is y''-5y'+10y = 10x, with y(0)=0 and y(1)=100. So I need a way to somehow obtain the coefficients that will multiply "y_i" from the relation:

[image]

And then store the resultant coefficients into a matrix, which will be the matrix of the system I'll solve trough Gauss-Jordan. The question boils down to how to obtain these coefficients and move them to the matrix. I thought about working out the coefficients by hand and then just inputing the matrix, but I need to do this for steps of size 0.1, 0.001 and 0.001, so that's really not a viable option here.

Comment: Aren't the coefficients right there?

Comment: In a sense, yes. For the 2nd point for instace we'd get the coefficients for y1,y2,y3 to be (-1-5h)/h^2, (-2-5h+10h^2)/h^2, 1/h^2, respectively. But these are just for the 2nd line of the system and I still need a way to move then to the matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume the more general case of the ODE

```
c1 * y''(x) + c2 * y'(x) + c3 * y(x) + c4 * x = 0
```

with the boundary conditions

```
y(0) = lo
y(1) = hi
```

And you want to solve this for `x ∈ [0, 1]` with a step size of `h = 1 / n` (where `n + 1` is the number of samples). We want to solve for the `yi = y(h * i)`. The `yi` range from `i ∈ [0, n]`. To do this, we want to solve a linear system

```
A y = b
```

Every interior `yi` will impose a single linear constraint. Hence, we have `n - 1` rows in `A` and `n - 1` columns corresponding to the unknown `yi`.

To set up `A` and `b`, we can simply slide a window over our unknown `yi` (I assume zero-based indexing).

```
A = 0  //the zero matrix
b = 0  //the zero vector
for i from 1 to n - 1
    //we are going to create the constraint for yi and store it in row i-1

    //coefficient for yi+1
    coeff = c1 / h^2 + c2 / h
    if i + 1 < n
        A(i - 1, i) = coeff
    else
        b(i - 1) -= coeff * hi  //we already know yi+1

    //coefficient for yi
    coeff = -2 * c1 / h^2 - c2 / h + c3
    A(i - 1, i - 1) = coeff

    //coefficient for yi-1
    coeff = c1 / h^2
    if i - 1 > 0
        A(i - 1, i - 2) = coeff
    else
        b(i - 1) -= coeff * lo  //we already know yi-1

    //coefficient for x
    b(i - 1) -= c4 * i * h
 next
```